# Horizontal UIScrollView with multiple textfields to display

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode6, uitextfield

I'm new to Xcode. I want to make a `UIScrollView` with multiple pages and each page having multiple `UITextFields` which vary on each page. I made `UIScrollView` with paging enabled. Now I'm stuck at displaying textfield's on scroll pages.

Here is my code so far:

```
//set the paging to yes
self.scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
// create 5 pages
 NSUInteger numberOfViews = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++)
{

    //set the origin of the sub view
    CGFloat myOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    //create the sub view and allocate memory
    myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    //create a label and add to the sub view
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 200.0f, 25.0f);
    textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    textLabel.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [myView addSubview:textLabel];

    //create a text field and add to the sub view
    myFrame.origin.y += myFrame.size.height + 10.0f;
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.tag = i+1;
    [myView addSubview:textField];
    //set the background to different color

    //set the scroll view delegate to self so that we can listen for changes
    self.scrollview.delegate = self;
    //add the subview to the scroll view
    [self.scrollview addSubview:myView];
}

//scroll horizontally
self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews,
                                         self.scrollview.frame.size.height);

//we set the origin to the 1rd page
CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0, 0);
//change the scroll view offset the the 1rd page so it will start from there
[scrollview setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

[self.view addSubview:self.scrollview];
```

}

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far

Comment: post my code as answer. sorry do not know how to put code in stack overflow

Comment: I've edited your question for you

Comment: what is an issue while dispaying textField?

Comment: i need to display multiple textfields on single page.how can i do this??

Comment: what should i use further to display many textfields on every page?

Comment: Why you don't create a UIPageViewController with UITableViewController as pages?

Comment: can i get horizontal scroll in UIPageViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This code here textfieldCount is

```
for (int j=0; j < textFieldCount; j++)
    {
        myFrame.origin.y += myFrame.size.height + 10.0f*(j+1);
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField.tag = j+1;
        [myView addSubview:textField];

    }
```

Hope you got your answer.